# Displaying only only orders where Customer has switched subscriptions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to query an Orders database to show which customers switched subscriptions from a high-cost subscription to a low cost subscription.

Each month, the subscriptions get billed and a new record gets created.

What I'm looking for is something like this but for all clients where they have purchased both AAAA and BBBB subscriptions:

```
PRODUCT CODE:      CUSTOMER NAME:            BILL DATE:
AAAA               Joey P.                   2018-01-01 
AAAA               Joey P.                   2018-02-01
BBBB               Joey P.                   2018-03-01
BBBB               Joey P.                   2018-04-01
```

In the above case, the customer switched to the cheaper subscription after two months.

I would like to query the table to include ALL customers who switched subscription levels. However, I'm getting stuck on being able to show ONLY customers who have purchased BOTH product codes. My query currently selects all the customers who have purchased one OR both products.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [productcode] AS "PRODUCT CODE"
    ,[customername] AS "CUSTOMER NAME"
    ,[billdate] AS "BILL DATE"
FROM mydatabase
WHERE YEAR([billdate]) > 2017
    AND ([productcode] = 'AAAA' OR [productcode] = 'BBBB')
```

I have tried self joins with no luck.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Any error? Wrong results?

Comment: Currently customers show up if they have only purchased one of the two products. I need a list of customers who have purchased both products.

Comment: Can you post your table definition and data example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
;WITH [Data] AS (
    SELECT m.customername,m.productcode,m.billdate
    FROM mydatabase m
    WHERE YEAR(m.[billdate]) > 2017
        AND m.productcode IN ('AAAA','BBBB')
)
SELECT d.productcode AS [PRODUCT CODE]
    ,d.customername AS [CUSTOMER NAME]
    ,d.billdate AS [BILL DATE]
FROM (
    SELECT m.customername
    FROM [Data] m
    GROUP BY m.customername
    HAVING MAX(m.productcode) <> MIN(m.productcode)
) a
INNER JOIN [Data] d ON d.customername = a.customername
;
```

Comment: this is a brilliant response but I'm wondering if you had a solution if I had to expand the query to include three separate products, not just two. I'm not sure how the min - max solution would work with three products instead of two.

Comment: Gordon's answer can help in this case. Try use HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.productcode) = 3 in the "a" subquery

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the *customers* who switched you can use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT customername
FROM mydatabase
WHERE YEAR([billdate]) > 2017 AND productcode IN ('AAAA', 'BBBB')
GROUP BY customername
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT productcode) = 2;
```

Comment: This works! However, I will need more columns from the database as well. Look like there are exactly 100 customers who bought both these products. I will need a row for every month the customer was billed (I realize this will create a large set of results), so the `group by` statement probably won't do the trick here.